# When/why is the solution for an RLC circuit differential equation actually useful?

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

Maybe it's an obvious answer that I'm missing, but I was trying to apply the Laplace transform to a differential equation for a maths assignment, and an RLC circuit differential equation was one of the few applications of a sufficiently complicated differential equation that I could justify using the Laplace transform for. But I need to actually justify why this application is useful, and I really don't know why. I have found the solution for my differential equation describing the RLC circuit so I guess I now have a time-varying current function.

But when is this useful?

Sorry for knowing nothing about circuits, in retrospect I should probably have found a different application.

Also, I feel like I should mention [this](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/analyze-an-rlc-circuit-using-laplace-methods/) is the method I am following since sometimes I see a Laplace method for RLC circuits seems to go in a different direction.

Comment: You mean, when does a time-varying function matter in electronics? Like, say, for working out overshoot, or settling time, or tuning complex filters, or stuff like that?

Comment: Every time you put a capacitor into a circuit, you're actually putting an RLC circuit since the capacitor has parasitic resistance and inductance. And capacitors often go in parallel for decoupling, which means many RLC circuits that can resonate with each other. Also, each inductor you put into a circuit it is also an RLC circuit for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different reasons you'd want to know the time or frequency domain response.

If you are making a relaxation oscillator, or any circuit where you want to time or delay something based on the time something charges/discharges, you'd want the time domain solution. If you are looking at how fast a circuit responds to a sudden change in a digital input, you'd want the time domain solution.

If you wanted to know how a filter responds to different frequencies, you'd want the frequency domain solution.